# How to use Redis on localhost WAMPP

Tags: redis, localhost, php-5.4

I have to use Redis with php. I am using windows8 OS and WAMPP as server. Is there ay way to install php extension for redis and work on it. Or how can i use redis on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the php redis extension compatible with your PHP version and put it in php extensions folder. Also, include it in your php.ini file and check phpinfo() if it shows the redis extension installed.